# SearchView in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

How can I implement a SearchView in my android project's RecyclerView like that one in **Google Play Store**?

I have already created a recyclerview which has a *dashboard. java*. This dashboard has *imageview*, *textview* and another *count textview*.

I need the search view to show the name of the *cardview* when search has been queried.

The data code is as follows:

```
Public class Dashboard {
   private String name;
   private int numOfItems;
   private int image;

Public Dashboard (){
}

Public Dashboard (String name, int numOfItems, int image)

 this.name = name;
 this.numOfItems = numOfItems;
 this.image = image;}
```

So I want to put a SearchView in the MainActivity to implement this search.

In my MainActivity, the data is shown as this:

```
private void prepareItems(){
      int [] covers = new int[]{
         R.drawable.image1,
         R.drawable.image2 };
 Dashboard item = new Dashboard (*name* "House", *numOfItems* "2", covers[0]); 
 menuList.add(item);

  Dashboard item = new Dashboard (*name* "City", *numOfItems* "29", covers[1]);
  menuList.add(item);

   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to research implementing a SearchView. A tutorial on how to do this is in the Android Documentation:

https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html

You need to implement a SearchView and then once you get the query from the searchview you can perform a search against your data.

When you get the results from your search you can display them in the recyclerview.

Please let me know what additional help I can provide in the comments.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain the details in the answer citing references from the link provided by you.

Comment: Of coz I followed that on the link you have provided, but maybe I am missing it. Will try

Comment: I tried to use the implement method in MainActivity, but with the cardview I have created, it is giving me errors.

Comment: @Blip - let me see if I can find an example implementation to provide